# MySQL queries don't work when query string is concatenated/ substituted from variables in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a string saved in a variable. That string is made from a couple other variables. If I echo it to a test page it shows up correctly, but if I try to update a mysql table with that variable it doesn't work.

It update the table, however when I use the actual string and no the variable.

Works:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$conn->query("UPDATE db SET columnx = 1 WHERE columny = 'y'");
```

Does not work:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$y = 'y';
$columnx = 'columnx';
$conn->query("UPDATE db SET $columnx = 1 WHERE columny = '$y'");
```

I've been at this for 2 days and still can't figure out why these strings are not being loaded to the table when I use a variable.

Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE db SET $columnx = 1 WHERE columny = '$y'";` then echo $sql to check its correct. But anyway, use PDO, and use prepared statements!

Comment: If a query does not work as expected, then you should check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see if there are any database errors.

Comment: PDO connection: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn

Comment: you ought to use prepared statements anyway - that would negate this issue

Comment: Prepared statements https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiexec

Comment: @delboy1978uk I'd love to use a prepared statement, but I can't substitute the column name in a prepared statement. I tried that. I also put the whole query in a variable and echoed it to make sure it was correct - it was.

Comment: I understand that. You only bind values, you can still build the query with the columns normally except for the values. give it a try!

Comment: You can still use prepared statements for the values, and you should.

Comment: Yes agreed, I did that for the values, but that doesn't solve the problem I asking about.

Comment: it isnt possible everything has updated when you ran the first query, and now there is nothing left to update with the second?

Comment: No I'm clearing the values before testing each time.

Comment: Abstracting the sample code is great and all. But this question isn't answerable without further details (such as a concrete error message).

Comment: There's no error showing up, query is executing, but the update is not happening.

Comment: Mysql errors do not show up like PHP errors do. You need to explicitly check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: I added `mysqli_error()` to a function and called the function on a test page, but nothing comes up.

Comment: Have you checked your server's error logs?